# How can I find the actual implementation of np.partition()?

Tags: python, numpy

To understand [how `numpy.partition()` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57564644/11566345) I am trying to read the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e1c42bb77fa727f0b214f3433207e20261acb57f/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L659).

```
if axis is None:
    # flatten returns (1, N) for np.matrix, so always use the last axis
    a = asanyarray(a).flatten()
    axis = -1
else:
    a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
a.partition(kth, axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
return a
```

which just encapsulates the input with numpy.asanyarray(), and calls itself.

this seems not be the actual implementation, how can I find the actual implementation of np.partition()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out, `np.partition` uses the method `partition` of `ndarray`, which itself is written in C, under the name `array_partition`.  [You can find its source here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/deea4983aedfa96905bbaee64e3d1de84144303f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L1289).  If you look into the source, you'll see it uses another C function internally, `PyArray_Partition`, [which can be found here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ea965e4cd328fbcf76b03ff749ef06d2aa38c28b/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L1232).

To find which source file contains which function, you can always use GitHub's search bar to search into a specific repo :-)

Comment: That is only half of it, `PyArray_Partition` is an outer function that in principle let's you choose between different algorithms (the`kind` parameter to `np.partition`). Currently only `introselect` ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect)) is available ([see here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h.src#L65-L89)), and the implementation is in [`numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src#L270-L405).

Comment: Thanks a lot. What keyword you used to find the connection between np.partition and array_partition? I searched with "np.partition" on GitHub and got "21 code results", which contains the "fromnumeric.py" file and other 20 helpless results.

Comment: Searching "partition" got me 34 code results, which contains the part you [link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/deea4983aedfa96905bbaee64e3d1de84144303f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L1289). How do I know this is what I need at the first glance. Do I need to go through all the results one by one? I usually ignore the results that involve "test".

Comment: @whnlp What I did was basically: I searched for "partition" like you did.  When I saw a bunch of C files in the results, I guessed it must be a part of NumPy implemented in C.  Then I just skimmed through the results to see what might contain the implementation, basing myself on the name of the file and the few lines of content displayed in the search results.

Comment: @whnlp Usually the trickiest part is to find the "bridge" between Python and C. A lot of array method mappings are in [`methods.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L2849-L2851). The function `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` used e.g. in [`array_partition`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L1283-L1349) is a good hint since it parses Python args. From there you can jump around to `PyArray_Partition`, `get_partition_func` and `*introselect_*`.